# My Raspberry Pi not booting

Tags: boot-issues

I'm using raspberry Pi since last week I tried to run but power led is ok but green LED Flashing 6 Times again and again. I tried all method reflashing os , Changing power supply etc.
Is there any solution ?

Comment: The foundation really should keep an up-to-date page about this, but they seem not to.  According to this: https://support.buyapi.ca/article/33-raspberry-pi-act-led-error-patterns 6 short flashes = power failure.

Comment: The Foundation has [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558)

Comment: [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) for older models